# Error after run "php artisan config:cache"

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

After run `php artisan config:cache` , show error in

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist
>   in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:729
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(729):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('config') #1
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(608):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config') #2
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(575):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config') #3
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(728):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config') #4
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(106):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('config') #5
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(269):
>   app('config') #6 D:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Ill
>   in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
>   on line 729

I add this Code On `bootstrap/app.php`

```
$app->bootstrapWith([
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\SetRequestForConsole::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders::class,
]);
```

new Error after added this code :

And run `composer dumpautoload -o`, it doesn't work

I added this code , it works

```
$app->bootstrapWith([
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\SetRequestForConsole::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders::class,
]);
```

but i use sluggable package and set method to config file , after set command , change sluggable package method array to this :

```
'method' =>
  Closure::__set_state(array(
)),
```

Now , my app doesn't work!
Because comment this code and work my code ! :(

Comment: what's your code ?

Comment: Delete vendor folder and run  `composer install`

Comment: Are you using dompdf ? You can check this issue if helpful, https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/192

Comment: Hit below commands in order

php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear

composer dump-autoload

php artisan config:cache

Comment: this problem in the sluggable.php file and method ( for support persian language ) :
```
'method' => function($string, $separator = '-')
    {
        $_transliteration = array(
            '/ä|æ|ǽ/' => 'ae',
            '/ö|œ/' => 'oe',
            '/ü/' => 'ue',
            '/Ä/' => 'Ae',
            '/Ü/' => 'Ue',
            '/Ö/' => 'Oe'
);
....